# Convert Guid to string name using enum and concat as string

Tags: c#

I want to send `Guid` to an enum and get string value. I.E

If I send `"642E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509"` I want it to return `Vodka`

I have multiple id's and each Guid represents different "drink"

Guid list:

```
642E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
652E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
662E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
672E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
682E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
692E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
6A2E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
6B2E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
6C2E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
6D2E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
6E2E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
6F2E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
702E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
712E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
722E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
732E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
742E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
752E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
```

How can I achieve that on an enum:

```
 public enum Drinks
    {
     [Display(Name ="Vodka")]
     642E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509
    }
```

And then how can I access process it on backend replace all Guid's for their current  drink name?

At the end of the day I want to get an string of drink names instead Guids:

```
string.Join(", ", model.DrinkList.Select(x => x.Id))
```

Comment: You can not create enum values with `-` in them. Also not starting with a number.

Comment: Do you have only limited set of drinks with id and name? Aren't they stored in  the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `Guid` as an identifier for an `enum`.

Try this instead:

```
void Main()
{
    var guid = Guid.Parse("652E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509");
    Console.WriteLine(_drinks[guid]);
}

private Dictionary<Guid, string> _drinks = new Dictionary<Guid, string>()
{
    { Guid.Parse("642E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509"), "Vodka" },
    { Guid.Parse("652E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509"), "Whisky" },
    { Guid.Parse("662E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509"), "Gin" },
};
```

When I run that code I get the value `Whisky` output on the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. An `enum` is just a named alias for an integer. A Guid/UUID is a 128-bit value and theoretically you could convert it to an integer and so accomplish that by casting.
.
.
.
But, since C#/.Net's largest support integer size is 64-bits, you are out of luck.

You should look at using `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` instead. Subclass class it and create an implementation that gives you the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach to wrap desired behavior with the custom class.
Custom class will have private constructor, so it's instances can be created only via static methods.

```
public class Drinks
{
    public Guid Key { get; }
    public Guid Name { get; }

    private Drinks(Guid key, string name) => (Key, Name) = (key, name);

    public static Drinks Find(Guid key) => Lookup[key];

    public static readonly Drinks Vodka = new Drinks(Guid.NewGuid(), "Vodka");
    public static readonly Drinks Whisky = new Whisky(Guid.NewGuid(), "Whisky");
    public static readonly Drinks Gin = new Gin(Guid.NewGuid(), "Gin");

    private static readonly ImmutableDictionary<Guid, Drinks> Lookup =
        new[] { Vodka, Whisky, Gin }.ToImmutableDictionary(d => d.Key);
}
```

Usage

```
var myDrinks = new[] { Drinks.Whisky };
var newDrink = Drinks.Find(Guid.Parse("652E1905-1111-EC11-9FFF-00155E011509"));
```

One benefit over `enum` is if this type is used as an argument in the method, consumer of the method will not be able to provide invalid "drink".